# Verbs or adjectives that go with "notebook"

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I have used up all pages in my notebook, so I need a new one. How should I put this in English?

*I (**verb**) my notebook. I need a new one.*

or

*My notebook is (**passive verb/adjective**). I need a new one.*

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

> I **filled** my notebook. I need a new one.
>   My notebook is **full**. I need a new one.

Comment: Here is another link about the same question: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/my-notebook-has-finished-ended.3409650/

Answer (score 1):

> I **finished** my notebook. I need a new one.

or

> I've **run out of space in** my notebook. I need a new one.

or

> My notepad is **used up**. I need a new one.

Comment: Finished and "used up" work well, but not "run out my note book."